# CSS-animations and Z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I will call my div elements layers, to make stack order clear. I have three layers, lets say, with a z-index of

layer 1, `z-index: 0;`
layer 2, `z-index: 1;`
layer 3, `z-index: 2;`

- Layer 1 is a div acting as the main page, as a first child element of the body element.
- Layer 2 is  the menu I want to animate  which needs to sow/hide on hover.
- Layer 3 is the inner page, child of layer 1 which layer 2 initially hides under(in terms of stack)

Here is a mockup of the elements:

[image]

I want to animate layer 2 from right to left till where the dotted line(end of element from the right) meets the left side of layer 3. Once layer 2 is fully shown, I want it to animate back to original position but with a z-index higher than of layer 3, allowing overlapping. When hover ends, layer 2 should animate the same way but with 'reversed' effects.

I  am quite new to css, and how it works. I am fully aware that jquery will come into play since events will be fired..

My questions

1. But what I am not full aware of, is how does the markup need to be set?
2. Does layer 2 need to be outside layer 1 and layer 3 ?(ie. not child of 1,3).
3. And does it need to have the position property set to absolute for
   this to work?
4. What about responsiveness? How can I deal with window resizing if
   the element is positioned with absolute?

Comment: Understanding how `z-index` works will take some effort on your part, you need to learn about stacking contexts first in order to use it effectively. MDN is always handy for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Thanks, this should help alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for markup:

- Place layer 2 inside layer 3
- Give layer 3 `position:relative;`
- Give layer 2 `position:absolute;`

That will make your top,left,right,bottom properties of layer 2 relative to the boundaries of layer 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I do not want layer3 part of layer2, as layer 2 is a menu. This doesn't seem quite right, am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/tCLNF/9/

Comment: Sorry i was mixing up layer 2 and 3.

Comment: I guess an element can never be deeper than it's parent. Maybe take layer 2 out of layer 3 and wrap them both in a div with position relative.

Comment: Yes just as I thought. I think an element cannot be stacked on top of a parent  element

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give css hover in layer 2 = z-index: 3

```
#layer1 {
z-index: 0;
}
#layer2 {
z-index: 1;
}

/* This CSS will display layer 2 in mouse hover and cover layer 3 */
#layer2:hover {
z-index: 3;
}

#layer3 {
z-index: 2;
}
```

and maybe you can try to show/hide css using javascript/jquery